# 3proxy config for user / pass authentication

Tags: proxy

I need to configure 3proxy server to allow IP based authentication, and / or username / password authentication.

When I use the IP based authentication it works fine.

With username / password authentication it does work, but 3proxy is asking for the username / password on every page load.

This is a snippet from my 3proxy server config file:

```
auth strong
users jsmcm:CL:mypassword
flush

allow jsmcm
proxy -p802 -a -i1.2.3.4 -e1.2.3.4
flush
```

Is there anything that I need to do to make it ask for the password only once per session? I tried adding the cache auth type but either I did that incorrectly, or it doesn't do what I thought it would do!

Comment: This question is about a proxy server.. Seems quite on topic for SERVERfault.com. Its not about end user computing nor about development. I did make the mortal sin of mentioning the development of a module in my initial post, but anyone who ACTUALLY read the question would understand that its about a proxy SERVER config...

Answer (score 1):

It was unobvious and complicated but I finally found out how to. Here's a sample config that aonly allows to connect using username "myuser" and password "mypassword":

```
users myuser:CL:mypassword 
auth strong
allow myuser
proxy
auth strong
allow myuser    
socks
```

So, first we sort of create user (we can create multiple users and use another password encryption method.) For all that info, use the official docs: https://3proxy.ru/howtoe.asp